# How can I format my thumb drive so that I can be read by Samsung Galaxy Tab tablet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab

I have a  Samsung Galaxy Tab with an usb adapter. 
how can I format my thumb drive so that it can be read by Samsung Galaxy tablet when attached?
And it also need to be readable by Windows OS so that i can transfer files between my tablet and my desktop?

I have tried 'FAT32' but Galaxy Tab can't read that format.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Android? What happens when you plug it into the tablet, does it not recognize it at all or say the filesystem is unsupported or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried FAT16?

As far as I am aware, the standard format for all SD CARDS is FAT16, so it should work for tablets as well.

Also, could it be that the system that you use to connect your drive to your galaxy tab is broken?

Comment: FAT16 is way old, though. The usual format for mass storage devices nowadays is [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) as the OP appears to have tried.